# Email confirm jquery

Tags: jquery

My goal is for the user to enter his email and then confirms it. If both aren't the same, the form show an error.

The code below works find except that if the user

- Enter: "bla@stack.com" on the email field;
- Enter: "bla@stack.com" on the confirm email field;
- go back to the email field and change the ""bla@stack.com" to "azerty@stack.com";
- doesn't change the confirm email field.

There is no error.

jquery:

```
//Vérifie si l'email et sa répetition son identiques
$('#RepetitionEmail').keyup(function(){

    var RepetitionEmail = $('#RepetitionEmail').val();

    if($("#RepetitionEmail").val()!=$("#Email").val())
    {
        $('#RepetitionEmail').css('border-color','orange');
        $('.ErreurRepetitionEmail').text('Pas encore les mêmes ...');
        checkRepetitionEmail = "Repetition email pas identique";
    }else
    {
        $('#RepetitionEmail').css('border-color','#00ff00');
        $('.ErreurRepetitionEmail').text('... ça y est!');
        checkRepetitionEmail = "Repetition email ok";
    }
});
```

Comment: Instead of `$('#RepetitionEmail').keyup` try `$('#RepetitionEmail, #Email').keyup` .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your selector to this

```
$('#RepetitionEmail, #Email').keyup(function(){
```

It will now listen to keyUp event on both inputs.

Answer (score 1):

What [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11668861/447356) is correct, you can improve the code. First, your current code will fail when user paste text using mouse only. Second, you have redundant code that can be optimized.

Here is a better way to achieve the same end result: (assuming you're using new jQuery version)

```
$("#MyForm").on("change", "#RepetitionEmail, #Email", function() {
    var tbEmail = $("#Email");
    var tbConfirmEmail = $("#RepetitionEmail");
    var email = tbEmail.val();
    var confirmEmail = tbConfirmEmail.val();
    if (email.length === 0 || confirmEmail.length === 0) {
        //user still did not fill up both.
        return;
    }

    var borderColor = "";
    var errorText = "";
    if(email !== confirmEmail)
    {
        borderColor = "orange";
        errorText = "Pas encore les mêmes ...";
        checkRepetitionEmail = "Repetition email pas identique";
    }else
    {
        borderColor = "#00ff00";
        errorText = "... ça y est!";
        checkRepetitionEmail = "Repetition email ok";
    }

    tbConfirmEmail.css('border-color', borderColor );
    $('.ErreurRepetitionEmail').text(errorText );
});
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/xaH59/).

​Handling the `change` event is better as it will work no matter how the text is being changed.

If you have more things to validate or want it to be more flexible, take a look in the numerous jQuery validation plugins.

Comment: I don't know if it's my browser or something but this code doesn't do the exact same effect. It doesn't show the error message "live". I have to click outside the input for the message to appear.

Comment: @RubleGomes that's because the `change` event only triggers when you leave the textbox and that's by design. All major websites use this for validation, check for yourself. (e.g. "this field is required" appears only when you leave the field)

Comment: Ah I see, like gmail. I don't really like that method to be honest.I prefer the "live" message, so the user doesn't have to go back and forth. Thank you for your answer anyway, I will optimize the code as you suggest but I think I'm gonna keep the keyup method.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#RepetitionEmail, #Email').keyup(function(){ // do something }
```